# Python keeps throwing a "TypeError" error for a list, and I do not understand why

Tags: python, typeerror

So, I'm kind of new to Python, and I'm trying to make a small command line menu system with lists, using the following code:

```
menu = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]

i = 0

for item in menu2:
    print(str(i) + str(menu[item]))
    i = i + 1
```

But whenever I run that code, I'm thrown the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening or how to fix it? I've tried most anything I can think of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. List indices should be integers, meaning that you should use menu[integer] instead of menu[item] when you want to access the str inside menu

Comment: `str(menu[item]))` is just `item` in the posted code, isn't it?

Comment: what's in `menu2` ?

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Speaking of, what do/don't you understand from that error message? By the way, you can use `enumerate()` instead of having to count values using `i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error when trying to access list by index - "List indices must be integers, not str"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198821/python-error-when-trying-to-access-list-by-index-list-indices-must-be-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove str also not needed menu. print statement should be like below.

```
print(i + item)
```

Comment: if this answer work for you please approve the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function

You are having a TypeError because *menu* is a list, not a string. It wants you to define the index to access the string inside the list.

```
menu = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]


for item in range(len(menu)):
    print(str(item) + str(menu[item]))
```