# Read out value from JSON

Tags: python

I am trying to read out 'epoch' from a JSON using json.loads (simplejson) but get an error telling me it is a string? But the output cleary shows epoch is an INT.
What am I missing?

CODE:

```
inputRecords = json.loads(inputRecordsJson) 
print(inputRecords) 
epochRead = inputRecords['epoch']
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'parameter': -0.92, 'epoch': 1583944863}]

Failed :  list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: It says your _list index_ is a string. You have a list of objects I think. You need to get the first item from the list `list[0]` and then you can look for your attribute.

Comment: try `inputRecords[0]['epoch']`

Comment: like @takendarkk said, You should try `inputRecords[0]['epoch']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error when trying to access list by index - "List indices must be integers, not str"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198821/python-error-when-trying-to-access-list-by-index-list-indices-must-be-integer)

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this code:

```
inputRecords = json.loads(inputRecordsJson) 
print(inputRecords)
```

We can see that `inputRecords` is a `list`.

So I imagine that this code:

```
epochRead = inputRecords[0]['epoch']
```

should find the entry in the `dict` within the `list`.

Comment: Thanks Martik. Someone was very quick to dish out downvotes. It seemed to me that I got a downvote at the same moment I answered.