# result.append([1,matches['main'][0]['rule']]) and got messages TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, linux, yara

im using this code below but it doesnt work.. content of `filepath` available here [peid.yara](https://github.com/urwithajit9/ClaMP/blob/master/scripts/peid.yara). full code here [integrated_feature_extraction.py](https://github.com/urwithajit9/ClaMP/blob/master/scripts/integrated_features_extraction.py)

```
def __init__(self,source,output,label):
        self.source = source
        self.output = output
        self.type = label
    #Need PEiD rules compile with yara
        self.rules= yara.compile(filepath='/home/osboxes/honeymalware/scripts/peid.yara')  
        
def check_packer(self,filepath):
        result=[]
        matches = self.rules.match(filepath)
        if matches == []:
               result.append([0,"NoPacker"])
        else:
               result.append([1,matches['main'][0]['rule']])
        return result
    
def main():    
        source_path= raw_input("Enter the path of samples (ending with /) >>  ")
        output_file= raw_input("Give file name of output file. (.csv) >>")
        label = raw_input("Enter type of sample( malware(1)|benign(0))>>")
```

when i run the program i get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "integrated_features_extraction.py", line 375, in <module>
    main()
  File "integrated_features_extraction.py", line 372, in main
    features.create_dataset()
  File "integrated_features_extraction.py", line 356, in create_dataset
    data = self.extract_all(filepath)
  File "integrated_features_extraction.py", line 330, in extract_all
    packer = self.check_packer(filepath)
  File "integrated_features_extraction.py", line 239, in check_packer
    result.append([1,matches['main'][0]['rule']])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

i think problem occurred while executing `result.append([1,matches['main'][0]['rule']])`.what is wrong with the code above ??. what should i do ??
The output should be "no packer" or rulename in filepath.

Comment: Nowhere in the code you provided can we learn what `matches` is, so there's nothing more we can tell than what the error message already says: you have a list somewhere, and you are trying to index it with a string. Maybe if was `matches`, maybe `matches['main'][0]`...

Comment: What do you expect `matches` to contain? Your error indicates it is a `list`, so needs integers to index it, whereas you seem to use `['main']`. (And no, there's nothing wrong with the syntax)

Comment: Hello @lik , Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please carefully read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error when trying to access list by index - "List indices must be integers, not str"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198821/python-error-when-trying-to-access-list-by-index-list-indices-must-be-integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the change in match() method of Yara module. Earlier a dictionary was return so that was accessing using a key but now it returns a list and so there was a need to change the code.

I have written the script so I have updated the same on the GitHub project page.

```
 else:
        #result.append([1,matches['main'][0]['rule']])

        result.append([1,matches[0]])
```

Thanks, everyone for finding and resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

List can be accessed using indexes, example matches[0], matches[1], matches[2] .. etc., In your program, you accessed a list using a string 'main' and 'rule', matches['main'][0]['rule'] which raises an exception for TypeError.